# NSIndexPath does not recognize item, section, or row as properties

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

When iOS 7.1 sends my viewController:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The indexPath object does not recognize the properties: item, section or row.  The expected values are section = 0, item = 0

The Debugger shows:

```
**indexPath NSIndexPath *   0xc000000000000016

 NSObject       
_indexes    NSUInteger *    NULL    
  *_indexes     
_length     
_reserved   void *  NULL
```

The log reports:

```
(lldb) po indexPath
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
(lldb) po indexPath.item
error: property 'item' not found on object of type 'NSIndexPath *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po indexPath.row
error: property 'row' not found on object of type 'NSIndexPath *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po indexPath.section
error: property 'section' not found on object of type 'NSIndexPath *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression****
```

Any ideas why this is happening and what to do about it?

Comment: Could you please add your code? It's hard to see what really happens

Comment: This is the code.   I mean that the results I've shown are immediately after the method is entered.  Nothing else has transpired.  Perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: You put only method name - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
without rest of code. I think there is some error. Anyway check if you put identifier to your cell. I have build a few collectionView and tableview and didn't get this issue at all.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do not use the getter/setter dot syntax, use **brackets**:

1. `po (int)[index row]`
2. `po (int)[index section]`

Note that the `(int)` is necessary to print the row/section as an integer rather than a hex. Other such useful formatting parameters for LLDB can be found [here](https://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html).

#### EDIT

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the IndexPath structure, which bridges to the NSIndexPath class. The IndexPath value type offers the same functionality as the NSIndexPath reference type, and the two can be used interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with Objective-C APIs. This behavior is similar to how Swift bridges standard string, numeric, and collection types to their corresponding Foundation classes.

1. `po index.row`
2. `po index.section`

work as expected. The comment on `p` vs. `po` still stands.

It is worth noting that you may use `IndexPath` in **Swift** instead of **NSIndexPath**, as described in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsindexpath).

Comment: Thank you gothic dev.  The problem lay elsewhere.  I don't know why Log showed such strange results.  Following your recommendation, the issue became clearer to me.

Comment: Check! Curious, what was it?

Comment: I was using section and item to reference an array of arrays, but the second "array" was actually an object whose property was the array I was trying to reach.  I messed up by not adding the property reference to the item object.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  You are using po with items that are ints, not objects.  The result is expected to be nil.

Answer (score 11):

You could try this, it works perfectly for me:

```
po (int)[indexPath row]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using po?  The resulting `row` and `section` of the NSIndexPath are `NSUIntegers`, or `long` `ints`, not objects.

While p means print, po means *print object*.

`NSIndexPath *is* an object.  The contents of it aren't.

Use p, instead of po.

`p [indexPath section]`

`p [indexPath row]`

`p indexPath.section`

`p indexPath.row`

I make the same mistake all the time.

---

**Note:** If using a `UIViewController` and extending it to have a UITableViewController delegate and datasource, make sure to import `UITableView.h` or `UIKit` into your header file.

This file adds extensions to NSIndexPath so that you can use row and section.  If you don't import the file that declares them, you will go mad wondering why `indexpath.row` and `indexpath.section` don't work.

If you want to access `row` and `section` of `NSIndexPath` outside of a `UITableViewController`, you will need to do those imports to get access to those extensions.

Comment: From using p instead of po -> error: no known method '-section'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: Odd.  It's possible that the NSIndexPath doesn't have the UITableView convenience methods for row and section.  Which method of UITableView are you getting this in?

Comment: I get the same results in the cellforrow delegate.

Comment: @AlexZavatone: my understanding is that it is not the end result that matters to `p` vs. `po`, it is the nature of how you get there. **p** prints local and global variables, whereas **po** prints the description of an ObjC object. `p` is effectively a lower level command, closer to the processor, while `po` sends a `-description` message to an object. They both should work.

Comment: Interesting insight into how it works.  That should be easy to test.  Thanks.

Comment: @AlexZavatone: your comment about convenience methods provided the answer in my case.  My class was importing Foundation instead of UIKit and therefore did not recognize section and gave a build error: Property 'section' not found on object of type 'NSIndexPath *'